# Generate react native code from sirius

Tags: eclipse, react-native, acceleo, eclipse-sirius

Good evening ,

I want to generate  react native code from the sirius but I do not know how and is it possible to use acceleo for that ??
Thanks for helping me .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they Sirius enables the editing of EMF models and Acceleo can read those EMF models and generate text based on your templates.  They both share the same underlying technology and are commonly used that way: 
- with a sirius based modeler to edit a domain specific model
- and Acceleo templates to generate text or code